# ButtonBar changes position when Stage is resizable

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a BoarderPane (decoration: UTILITY) where a ButtonBar with two buttons is put to BOTTOM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="pw.yaps.client.jfx.view.SettingsViewController">
   <bottom>
      <ButtonBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <buttons>
          <Button disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" text="OK" />
            <Button cancelButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCancelAction" text="Cancel" />
        </buttons>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="12.0" right="12.0" />
         </padding>
      </ButtonBar>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

When the Stage is NOT resizable the layout looks like that:
[image]
but when I set it resizable it looks different:
[image]

How can this behavior be avoided?

Comment: Give the buttons a `Margin` and not the `MainPane` a `Padding`. This sould work.

Comment: @Developper66 Is there a default margin to use so the UI looks "natural" like other applications?

Comment: I do not think there is such a thing

Comment: @Developer66 I just checked: You cannot give a `Maring` to a Button, not with SceneBuilder anyways.